# How can I rotate marker with animation in Google Map Like Uber or OLA Cab app?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

How can I rotate marker with animation in Google Map Like Uber or OLA Cab app? I have done movement of marker from source to destination LatLng. But need to rotate it with animation before moving like OLA app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Google map marker orientation according path direction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23149613/change-google-map-marker-orientation-according-path-direction)

Comment: @geocodezip I am looking for native platform. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: please add android tag in your post

Answer (score 0):

Google map marker icon has a property `rotation` which can be set accordingly.

Example:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position : new google.maps.LatLng(35.678494,139.744205),
    map: myMap,
    icon: {
        url: '../images/car.png',
    // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50),
        rotation: 45
    }
  });
```

This will rotate your marker. You can also set this property on some event like button click of value changed etc.

But if you want rotation with animation then you can try adding this in your css file:

```
img[src^='../images/car.png']{
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
   transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}

img[src^='../images/car.png']:hover{
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Reference : https://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/nBsh4/

I found another great example of custom animation http://dylanvann.com/custom-animated-google-maps-markers/

Comment: Sorry, I am looking for Native Android code. Not expecting Hybrid. Thank you.