# What shall I do to remove the Poly line, (A) & (B) markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I found this code to track vehicle based on location sent by GPS device
but I don't know how to remove the (A,B) markers and also I don't want to draw the poly line.

Here is the code I use:

```
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23149613/change-google-map-marker-

orientation-according-path-direction
var map;
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService;
var stepDisplay;
//var markerArray = [];
var position;
var marker = null;
var polyline = null;
var poly2 = null;
var speed = 0.000005, wait = 1;
var infowindow = null;
var timerHandle = null;
var arrMarkers = [];
var markerIcon = '/Images/school-bus.png';

function getMarkerCurrentLocation(deviceId) {
    debugger;
    var mrkr = getMarkerByDeviceId(deviceId);
    if (mrkr != null && mrkr != undefined) {
        //var mrkrLat = mrkr.getPosition().lat();
        //var mrkrLng = mrkr.getPosition().lng();
        var mrkrLat = mrkr.lat;
        var mrkrLng = mrkr.lng;
        return new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(mrkrLat), parseFloat(mrkrLng));
    }
}

function addMarker(deviceId, lat, lng) {
    debugger;
    //var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    //    position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng)),
    //    icon: markerIcon,
    //    zIndex: Math.round(lat * -100000) << 5,
    //    map: map
    //});
    //marker.id = deviceId;
    arrMarkers.push({ deviceId: deviceId, lat: lat, lng: lng });
}

function getMarkerByDeviceId(deviceId) {
    debugger;
    return arrMarkers.filter(function (obj) {
        return obj.deviceId == deviceId;
    })[0];
}

function removeFromArrMarkersByDeviceId(deviceId) {
    debugger;
    arrMarkers = arrMarkers.filter(function (obj) {
        return obj.deviceId !== deviceId;
    });
}

function initialize() {
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
    });
    // Instantiate a directions service.
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    // Create a map and center it on Manhattan.
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: { lat: 21.3891, lng: 39.8579 }
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

    // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
    var rendererOptions = {
        map: map
    };
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

    // Instantiate an info window to hold step text.
    stepDisplay = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [],
        //strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 9.0,
        strokeWeight: 0
    });
    poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [],
        //strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 9.0,
        strokeWeight: 0
    });
}

var steps = [];

function calcRoute(deviceId, destinationLat, destinationLng) {
    console.log(deviceId);
    if (deviceId == "50204") {
        debugger;
        var mrkr = getMarkerByDeviceId(deviceId);
        if (mrkr != null && mrkr != undefined) {
            if (mrkr.lat != destinationLat | mrkr.lng != destinationLng) {
                debugger;
                if (timerHandle) {
                    clearTimeout(timerHandle);
                }
                if (marker) {
                    marker.setMap(null);
                }
                polyline.setMap(null);
                poly2.setMap(null);
                directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
                polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: [],
                    //strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                    strokeWeight: 0
                });
                poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: [],
                    //strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                    strokeWeight: 0
                });
                // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
                var rendererOptions = {
                    map: map
                };
                debugger;
                directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
                var start = getMarkerCurrentLocation(deviceId);
                var end = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(destinationLat), parseFloat(destinationLng));

                removeFromArrMarkersByDeviceId(deviceId);
                addMarker(deviceId, destinationLat, destinationLng);

                var travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING;

                var request = {
                    origin: start,
                    destination: end,
                    travelMode: travelMode
                };

                // Route the directions and pass the response to a
                // function to create markers for each step.
                directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

                        //var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                        var route = response.routes[0];
                        startLocation = new Object();
                        endLocation = new Object();

                        // For each route, display summary information.
                        var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
                        var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
                        for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
                            if (i === 0) {
                                startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
                                startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
                                // marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location, "start", legs[i].start_address, "green");
                            }
                            endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
                            endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
                            var steps = legs[i].steps;
                            for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
                                var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
                                for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
                                    polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                                    //bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //polyline.setMap(map);
                        //map.fitBounds(bounds);
                       //map.setZoom(18);
                        startAnimation(deviceId);
                    }
                });
            }

        } else {
            // debugger;
            addMarker(deviceId, destinationLat, destinationLng);
        }
    }
}
var step = 50; // 5; // metres
var tick = 1000; // milliseconds
var eol;
var k = 0;
var stepnum = 0;
var speed = "";
var lastVertex = 1;

//=============== animation functions ======================
function updatePoly(d) {
    // Spawn a new polyline every 20 vertices, because updating a 100-vertex poly is too slow
    if (poly2.getPath().getLength() > 20) {
        poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline([polyline.getPath().getAt(lastVertex - 1)]);
        // map.addOverlay(poly2)
    }

    if (polyline.GetIndexAtDistance(d) < lastVertex + 2) {
        if (poly2.getPath().getLength() > 1) {
            poly2.getPath().removeAt(poly2.getPath().getLength() - 1);
        }
        poly2.getPath().insertAt(poly2.getPath().getLength(), polyline.GetPointAtDistance(d));
    } else {
        poly2.getPath().insertAt(poly2.getPath().getLength(), endLocation.latlng);
    }
}

function animate(d) {
    if (d > eol) {
        //map.panTo(endLocation.latlng);
        marker.setPosition(endLocation.latlng);
        return;
    }
    var p = polyline.GetPointAtDistance(d);
    //map.panTo(p);
    var lastPosn = marker.getPosition();
    marker.setPosition(p);
    var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(lastPosn, p);
    icon.rotation = heading;
    marker.setIcon(icon);
    updatePoly(d);
    timerHandle = setTimeout("animate(" + (d + step) + ")", tick);
}

function startAnimation(deviceId) {
    debugger;
    eol = polyline.Distance();
    //map.setCenter(polyline.getPath().getAt(0));
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: polyline.getPath().getAt(0),
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        deviceId: deviceId
    });

    poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [polyline.getPath().getAt(0)],
        //strokeColor: "#0000FF",
        strokeWeight: 0
    });
    // map.addOverlay(poly2);
    setTimeout("animate(50)", 2000); // Allow time for the initial map display
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

//=============== ~animation funcitons =====================

var car = "M17.402,0H5.643C2.526,0,0,3.467,0,6.584v34.804c0,3.116,2.526,5.644,5.643,5.644h11.759c3.116,0,5.644-2.527,5.644-5.644 V6.584C23.044,3.467,20.518,0,17.402,0z M22.057,14.188v11.665l-2.729,0.351v-4.806L22.057,14.188z M20.625,10.773 c-1.016,3.9-2.219,8.51-2.219,8.51H4.638l-2.222-8.51C2.417,10.773,11.3,7.755,20.625,10.773z M3.748,21.713v4.492l-2.73-0.349 V14.502L3.748,21.713z M1.018,37.938V27.579l2.73,0.343v8.196L1.018,37.938z M2.575,40.882l2.218-3.336h13.771l2.219,3.336H2.575z M19.328,35.805v-7.872l2.729-0.355v10.048L19.328,35.805z";
var icon = {
    path: car,
    scale: .7,
    strokeColor: 'white',
    strokeWeight: .10,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    fillColor: '#404040',
    offset: '5%',
    // rotation: parseInt(heading[i]),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 25) // orig 10,50 back of car, 10,0 front of car, 10,25 center of car
};

/*********************************************************************\
*                                                                     *
* epolys.js                                          by Mike Williams *
* updated to API v3                                  by Larry Ross    *
*                                                                     *
* A Google Maps API Extension                                         *
*                                                                     *
* Adds various Methods to google.maps.Polygon and google.maps.Polyline *
*                                                                     *
* .Contains(latlng) returns true is the poly contains the specified   *
*                   GLatLng                                           *
*                                                                     *
* .Area()           returns the approximate area of a poly that is    *
*                   not self-intersecting                             *
*                                                                     *
* .Distance()       returns the length of the poly path               *
*                                                                     *
* .Bounds()         returns a GLatLngBounds that bounds the poly      *
*                                                                     *
* .GetPointAtDistance() returns a GLatLng at the specified distance   *
*                   along the path.                                   *
*                   The distance is specified in metres               *
*                   Reurns null if the path is shorter than that      *
*                                                                     *
* .GetPointsAtDistance() returns an array of GLatLngs at the          *
*                   specified interval along the path.                *
*                   The distance is specified in metres               *
*                                                                     *
* .GetIndexAtDistance() returns the vertex number at the specified    *
*                   distance along the path.                          *
*                   The distance is specified in metres               *
*                   Returns null if the path is shorter than that      *
*                                                                     *
* .Bearing(v1?,v2?) returns the bearing between two vertices          *
*                   if v1 is null, returns bearing from first to last *
*                   if v2 is null, returns bearing from v1 to next    *
*                                                                     *
*                                                                     *
***********************************************************************
*                                                                     *
*   This Javascript is provided by Mike Williams                      *
*   Blackpool Community Church Javascript Team                        *
*   http://www.blackpoolchurch.org/                                   *
*   http://econym.org.uk/gmap/                                        *
*                                                                     *
*   This work is licenced under a Creative Commons Licence            *
*   http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/uk/                    *
*                                                                     *
***********************************************************************
*                                                                     *
* Version 1.1       6-Jun-2007                                        *
* Version 1.2       1-Jul-2007 - fix: Bounds was omitting vertex zero *
*                                add: Bearing                         *
* Version 1.3       28-Nov-2008  add: GetPointsAtDistance()           *
* Version 1.4       12-Jan-2009  fix: GetPointsAtDistance()           *
* Version 3.0       11-Aug-2010  update to v3                         *
*                                                                     *
\*********************************************************************/

// === first support methods that don't (yet) exist in v3
google.maps.LatLng.prototype.distanceFrom = function (newLatLng) {
    var EarthRadiusMeters = 6378137.0; // meters
    var lat1 = this.lat();
    var lon1 = this.lng();
    var lat2 = newLatLng.lat();
    var lon2 = newLatLng.lng();
    var dLat = (lat2 - lat1) * Math.PI / 180;
    var dLon = (lon2 - lon1) * Math.PI / 180;
    var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    var d = EarthRadiusMeters * c;
    return d;
}

google.maps.LatLng.prototype.latRadians = function () {
    return this.lat() * Math.PI / 180;
}

google.maps.LatLng.prototype.lngRadians = function () {
    return this.lng() * Math.PI / 180;
}

// === A method which returns the length of a path in metres ===
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.Distance = function () {
    var dist = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < this.getPath().getLength() ; i++) {
        dist += this.getPath().getAt(i).distanceFrom(this.getPath().getAt(i - 1));
    }
    return dist;
}

// === A method which returns a GLatLng of a point a given distance along the path ===
// === Returns null if the path is shorter than the specified distance ===
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetPointAtDistance = function (metres) {
    // some awkward special cases
    if (metres == 0) return this.getPath().getAt(0);
    if (metres < 0) return null;
    if (this.getPath().getLength() < 2) return null;
    var dist = 0;
    var olddist = 0;
    for (var i = 1;
      (i < this.getPath().getLength() && dist < metres) ; i++) {
        olddist = dist;
        dist += this.getPath().getAt(i).distanceFrom(this.getPath().getAt(i - 1));
    }
    if (dist < metres) {
        return null;
    }
    var p1 = this.getPath().getAt(i - 2);
    var p2 = this.getPath().getAt(i - 1);
    var m = (metres - olddist) / (dist - olddist);
    return new google.maps.LatLng(p1.lat() + (p2.lat() - p1.lat()) * m, p1.lng() + (p2.lng() - p1.lng()) * m);
}

// === A method which returns an array of GLatLngs of points a given interval along the path ===
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetPointsAtDistance = function (metres) {
    debugger;
    var next = metres;
    var points = [];
    // some awkward special cases
    if (metres <= 0) return points;
    var dist = 0;
    var olddist = 0;
    for (var i = 1;
      (i < this.getPath().getLength()) ; i++) {
        olddist = dist;
        dist += this.getPath().getAt(i).distanceFrom(this.getPath().getAt(i - 1));
        while (dist > next) {
            var p1 = this.getPath().getAt(i - 1);
            var p2 = this.getPath().getAt(i);
            var m = (next - olddist) / (dist - olddist);
            points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(p1.lat() + (p2.lat() - p1.lat()) * m, p1.lng() + (p2.lng() - p1.lng()) * m));
            next += metres;
        }
    }
    return points;
}

// === A method which returns the Vertex number at a given distance along the path ===
// === Returns null if the path is shorter than the specified distance ===
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetIndexAtDistance = function (metres) {
    // some awkward special cases
    if (metres == 0) return this.getPath().getAt(0);
    if (metres < 0) return null;
    var dist = 0;
    var olddist = 0;
    for (var i = 1;
      (i < this.getPath().getLength() && dist < metres) ; i++) {
        olddist = dist;
        dist += this.getPath().getAt(i).distanceFrom(this.getPath().getAt(i - 1));
    }
    if (dist < metres) {
        return null;
    }
    return i;
}
// === Copy all the above functions to GPolyline ===
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.Distance = google.maps.Polygon.prototype.Distance;
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.GetPointAtDistance = google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetPointAtDistance;
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.GetPointsAtDistance = google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetPointsAtDistance;
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.GetIndexAtDistance = google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetIndexAtDistance;
```

[The Route Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE5Yz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var rendererOptions = {
    map: map,
    suppressMarkers: true
};
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
```

If you don't want to display something on your map then remove map: map.
Not sure if the rest of the code does wat is must do (like zoom and pan according to the route display)

```
var rendererOptions = {
    map: null,
    suppressMarkers: true
};
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
```

Comment: thanks so much markers disappeared but how can I hide the poly line too?

Comment: map: null instead of map: map